# How can I parse this string using NSString?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, string, nsstring

I have the following string:

```
callback({"Outcome":"Success", "Message":null, "Identity":"Request", "Delay":0.002, "Symbol":"AAPL", "CompanyName":"Apple Inc.", "Date":"1\/13\/2011", "Time":"4:02:36 PM", "Open":344.6, "Close":345.93, "PreviousClose":344.42, "High":346.63, "Low":343.86, "Last":345.93, "Change":1.51, "PercentChange":0.438, "Volume":785960})
```

I want my final string to not contain `callback(` and the the last `)` at the end of the string. How can I modify this NSString?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an `NSMutableString` out of it, called `string`. i.e. `NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString stringWithString:myString];`.

Then do `string = [string substringToIndex:[string length]-1];` and then `string = [string substringFromIndex:9];` or some such.

Or, again create an `NSMutableString` instance with your `NSString` instance, and call `[string replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"callback(" withString:@"" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];` and `[string replaceOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@"" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];`. This might be preferred.

Either way, then create an `NSString` instance with the new string, something like `goodString = [NSString stringWithString:string];` if you need an `NSString` out of this.

Comment: That will not mutate the original string even if you're using an NSMutableString.

Comment: @Chuck: That's right. The original string is of course unchanged. It's also not necessary to mutate anything. We also don't need `NSMutableString`s here, so my post is overkill. However, Alam seems to be under the impression that you can modify an `NSString` which you can't.

Answer (score 3):

NSScanner is a good fit for this sort of thing.

```
NSString *json = nil;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:fullString];
[scanner scanUpToString:@"{" intoString:NULL]; // Scan to where the JSON begins
[scanner scanUpToString:@")" intoString:&json];

NSLog(@"json = %@", json);
```

Comment: Or, scan up to the (, then scan it into the same black hole, then scan up to the ). Either way, though, this will fail if the JSON contains a ) (e.g., within a string).

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify an NSString (only an NSMutableString), but you can use `[string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(9, [string length] - 10)]`. To actually mutate an NSMutableString, you'd have to use two `deleteCharactersInRange:` calls to trim the parts you don't want.